# Create user on Azure AD using graph api is failing with error code 415

Tags: rest, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create new Azure AD user using graph, Http reqeuste url used is give below,

```
https://graph.windows.net/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.5
```

request type is "**POST**" request body looks like

```
{   "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Alex Wu",
    "mailNickname": "AlexW",
    "passwordProfile": { "password" : "Test1234", "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false },
    "userPrincipalName": "Alex@xyz.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Header

```
Authorization: Bearer 'access token value'
Content-Type:  application/json
```

On executing above request, I am getting response code 415, I guess this is because of **Content-Type**. I have tried various combination of Content-Type like `application/json;odata=minimalmetadata`, `application/json;odata=verbose` but it still returns response 415. Am I missing something in header ? 
When I tried same request through POSTMAN, it is working but if I do same using java application it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add header "Accept". This solved the problem for me:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: The content-type header should be application/json as well. 
Otherwise 415 will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn`, not `forceChangePasswordNextLogin`.